# Classic ASP XML, no errors but no results

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I have been working on a classic ASP site and there is one page I want to use XML for. So, trying to be smart to test sample code first from what I can find on the internet so I know what works or not with the hosting. As of now, the code not rendering anything in the browser. I don't have any errors. Just a blank page. I have tried `MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0` and still nothing. Is it possible the small hosting company disabled XML or something wrong with the code? I been trying for months. Please help and thank you.

Classic ASP

```
<%   

Set objXMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")    
objXMLDoc.async = False    
objXMLDoc.load Server.MapPath("xml.xml")

Dim xmlProduct       
For Each xmlProduct In objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("Product")
     Dim productCode : productCode = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("ProductCode").text   
     Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(productCode) & " "  
Next   
%>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Product>
   <ProductCode>abc</ProductCode>
</Product>
```

Comment: The current version is `MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0`

Answer (score 1):

Adding a "/" in front of Product should select the Product node.

```
Dim xmlProduct       
For Each xmlProduct In objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("/Product")
     Dim productCode : productCode = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("ProductCode").text   
     Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(productCode) & " "  
Next
```

Comment: thank you Luke Ford. such a simple thing yet so hard. everything works now in both tests. now I can begin to finish what i started. thanks again!